# How to include nuget lib's dll.config into my project's output binary folder?

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I have an SDK style C# project "HelloWorld" whose .csproj is like below

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net472</TargetFramework>
    <LangVersion>8</LangVersion>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="ABCLibrary" Version="1.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

The `ABCLibrary` files in my local nuget cache are under
`C:\Users\MyUsername\.nuget\packages\abclibrary.retail-amd64\1.0.0\lib\net472` and have such files:

- ABCLibrary.dll
- ABCLibrary.dll.config

When I build my project "HelloWorld", the output binary folder only has `ABCLibrary.dll` but no `ABCLibrary.dll.config`. But the dll depends on some settings in the config so I get exceptions.

An optional solution is to add the following in my "HelloWorld.csproj":

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="$(NuGetPackageRoot)\abclibrary.retail-amd64\1.0.0\lib\$(TargetFramework)\ABCLibrary.dll.config">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </None>
</ItemGroup>
```

But it's too ugly and troublesome. Is there a better way to include `ABCLibrary.dll.config` into the binary folder?

Comment: I'm afraid you have to go for the ugly approach

Comment: @mu88 Thanks. I was thinking it's a very common problem and could have a general solution because libraries usually have their own dll.configs.

Comment: Well, the typical .NET approach is to take the config settings you need and embed it into your own config. You see this very often with the `<assemblyBinding>` tags

Comment: @mu88 I see, thanks much. At least the ugly approach works :-P